# How to test for equality with custom comparator?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to generalise an implementation of *Binary Seach* by providing an additional argument: *Custom Comparator*:

```
template <typename T, typename It>  // Not sure if right !
struct LessCmp
{
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, It rhs)
    {
        return lhs < *rhs;
    }
};

template <typename It, typename T, typename Cmp>
bool binary_search(It begin, It end, const T& target, Cmp op) // Not sure if right !
{
    while (begin != end)
    {
        auto offset  = std::distance(begin, end);
        It middle = begin;
        std::advance(middle, offset / 2);

        if (/* how ? */)             // target == middle
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (op(target, middle)) // target < middle
        {
            end = middle;
        }    
        else                         // target > middle
        {
            begin = middle;
            std::advance(begin, 1);
        }
    } 

    return false
}
```

How to perform equality test with `LessCmp`? How to implement `LessCmp` so that it can be used in `binary_seach()`?

Comment: If !(x<y) and !(y<x), then (x==y) (for the kind of comparator you can use in binary search).

Comment: if(!comparator(a,b) && !comparator(b,a)) // i.e equal

Comment: this seems like too much thinking problem. `if op(target,middle) { ; } else if op(middle,target) { ; } else {return true;}`

Comment: Would you also explain why you are implementing a `binary_search()`, given that the standard library has one already, specified with the same template arguments/types you are using?

Comment: @Peter Chapter 26 Exercise 3 of _"C++ Programming: Principles and Practice"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `op` defines a strict total order over `T`.

```
if(op(target, middle))
{
     // target is less than middle
}
// target could be equal or greater than middle
// if middle is less than target, then target is greater
else if (op(middle, target))
{
    // target is greater than middle
}
else
{
    // target is equal to middle
}
```

Comment: The `else if` statement implies the existing of: `bool operator()(It rhs, const T& lhs);` , right? Note that `middle` and `target` are of different type.

Comment: @Ziezi: yes. I suggest having `bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)` instead and dereferencing appropriately when invoking `op`.